# Selenium is not working on proper way

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pdfkit
import time
import logging

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankurkhandelwal1/')
time.sleep(20)
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')


elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".contact-see-more-less.link-without-visited-state")
elem.click()

for div in soup.select('.pv-contact-info__ci-container'):
    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'pv-contact-info__contact-link Sans-15px-black-55%'}):
        old=link.get('href')
        mobile=old.replace("tel:", " ")

print(mobile)
```

`elem.click()` is working but after this line program doesn't go next and shows mobile blank. When I remove this line and manually click then it's working.

Comment: Post your error message, please.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testlkdn3.py", line 79, in <module>
    print(mobile)
NameError: name 'mobile' is not defined